# Simplify the execution of a python test within a shell script

Tags: python, shell

How would you simplify and give this shell script a nice look? Maybe using loops etc..

> `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
>
> `echo 'Testing 1'`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_1 python27 -m unittest test1`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_1 python27 -m unittest test2`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_1 python27 -m unittest test3`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_1 python27 -m unittest test4`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_1 python27 -m unittest test5`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_1 python27 -m unittest test6`
>
> `echo 'Testing 2'`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_2 python27 -m unittest test1`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_2 python27 -m unittest test2`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_2 python27 -m unittest test3`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_2 python27 -m unittest test4`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_2 python27 -m unittest test5`
>
> `CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_2 python27 -m unittest test6`

Comment: Unit tests should be fast.  You'd be better off combining the tests into a single file (or at least load them into a single python instance) and reduce the overhead of starting that python27 process for every testcase.

Answer (score 1):

just make a double loop

```
for i in 1 2
do
  echo "Testing $i"
  for j in 1 2 3 4 5 6
  do
      CONF_PATH=/var/..../test_$i python27 -m unittest test$j
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

just plug your commands where the echos are for how you want it..

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TESTGROUPS=$1
TESTS=$2

# Loop groups
for i in `seq 1 $TESTGROUPS`
do
  echo "TESTGROUP $i"
  # Loop tests                                                                                                                                     
  for j in `seq 1 $TESTS`
  do
    echo "TEST $j"
  done
done
```

execute with

```
./test.sh 2 3
```

would result in

```
TESTGROUP 1                                                                                                                                        
TEST 1                                                                                                                                             
TEST 2                                                                                                                                             
TEST 3                                                                                                                                             
TESTGROUP 2                                                                                                                                        
TEST 1                                                                                                                                             
TEST 2                                                                                                                                             
TEST 3
```